# Python Can Run with Typing "python.exe" Rather Typing "python"

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, python

I have added python to env on `PATH` correctly `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\`

But now I need to type `python.exe` to start it rather than typing `python` like before

And it will pop out a new window of python.exe rather run than on powershell directly

The same issue happened to my bito , I can run bito without typing `bito.exe` on powershell before, but now it does not work, the command must be `bito.exe`, and it does not run on powershell but start a new window

Before this issue appear, in order to run python script on powershell directly, I created `PATHEXT` env and added `.py`, but I found that it still does now work so I removed the env

But it seems that it has extra influence on my powershell and result in that **I need to type ext to run python on powershell**

I have no idea about what happened

Comment: You accidentally remove the path to your Python environment from your PATH system variable you need to add it back

Comment: You might have more than one `python` in your path. In CMD, run `where python` to check. In PowerShell use `gcm python` which is more general in some cases.

Comment: Did you remove PATHEXT completely, or did you only remove the .py entry from it?

Comment: @harrymc I have checked and it seems that there is one python```CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     python.exe                                         3.8.115... C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\...
```

Comment: @Ramhound but there is no PATHEXT before, I did not see it on env, that makes me confused

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes, I removed it totally, both `.py` and `exe`

Comment: Which shell are you using in PowerShell  ?

Comment: @Michael - Focus on the PATH variable not PATHEXT

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, so restore it back to the original value. PATHEXT is what used to add the .exe for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Before this issue appear, in order to run python script on powershell directly, I created PATHEXT env and added .py, but I found that it still does now work so I removed the env
>
> But it seems that it has extra influence on my powershell and result in that I need to type ext to run python on powershell

The PATHEXT variable is not just for .py scripts – it is also what allowed you to omit the `.exe` before. Do not remove it; make sure to set it back to its original value.

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
```